# C# Rijndael Decryption doesn't work with jpgs

Tags: c#-4.0, encryption, jpeg, rijndael

When I tried to encrypt and decrypt a simple string, everything went perfectly fine..

But when I encoded a jpg into a bytearray and did the exact same thing with that bytearray, the decryption didn't work anymore (the bytearray is completely different to the original one and cannot be displayed anymore)...

Is it because the bytearray is too big?

Or does someone have a solution for my problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Encrypter2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {

                Console.WriteLine();
                // Create a new instance of the Rijndael
                // class.  This generates a new key and initialization 
                // vector (IV).
                byte[] originalFile = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:/Users/Elron/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/FileEncrypt/FileEncrypt/bin/Debug/harambe.jpg");
                using (Rijndael myRijndael = Rijndael.Create())
                {
                //     Encrypt the string to an array of bytes
                //    Encrypted byte[]
                byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes(originalFile, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);
                    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(@"C:/Users/Elron/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/FileEncrypt/FileEncrypt/bin/Debug/harambeEncrypted.jpg"))
                    {
                        //Add some information to the file.
                        fs.Write(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);
                    }
                //     Decrypted byte[]
                byte[] roundtrip = DecryptStringFromBytes(encrypted, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);
                    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(@"C:/Users/Elron/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/FileEncrypt/FileEncrypt/bin/Debug/harambeDecrypted.jpg"))
                    {
                        //Add some information to the file.
                        fs.Write(roundtrip, 0, roundtrip.Length);
                    }
                //    Display the original data and the decrypted data.
                //    Encrypted string
                    Console.ReadKey();
            }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }

        static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes(byte[] plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
            byte[] encrypted;
            // Create an Rijndael object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (Rijndael rijAlg = Rijndael.Create())
            {
                rijAlg.Key = Key;
                rijAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for encryption.
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {

                            //Write all data to the stream.
                            string toEncrypt = Encoding.Default.GetString(plainText);
                            swEncrypt.Write(toEncrypt);
                        }
                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }


            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
            return encrypted;

        }

        static byte[] DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

            // Declare the string used to hold
            // the decrypted text.
            string plaintext = null;
            byte[] returnText;

            // Create an Rijndael object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (Rijndael rijAlg = Rijndael.Create())
            {
                rijAlg.Key = Key;
                rijAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for decryption.
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {
                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                            // and place them in a string.
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();


                            ASCIIEncoding asc = new ASCIIEncoding();
                            returnText = asc.GetBytes(plaintext);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return returnText;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It makes no sense to use the StreamReader and StreamWriter, which are for text, on binary data. Where did you copy-paste this code from, and do you understand what it's doing? What problem are you trying to solve in the first place?

Comment: I copied it from the MSDN page and watched a lot of Stream tutorials afterwards and tried to understand it, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using different Encodings in your encryption and decryption methods

```
static byte[] DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
    ...
    ASCIIEncoding asc = new ASCIIEncoding();
    returnText = asc.GetBytes(plaintext);
    ...
}
```

And

```
   static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes(byte[] plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        ...
        string toEncrypt = Encoding.Default.GetString(plainText);
        swEncrypt.Write(toEncrypt);
        ...
    }
```

Comment: As a side note, I found no point in `File -> byte[] -> string -> Encrypt -> string -> byte[]` keep is simple to avoid errors

Comment: well thanks i will have a look at that! that whole converting stuff is because when i did not do that i just got returned System.Byte[]; which wasn't useful back then... and when i tried to directly do it without all the converting stuff i got a bunch of errors because the write operations need a string and cannot be properly converted or something like that

Comment: note: the encoding was the problem! Thanks very much!

Comment: @Mreifenberger Glad to help, please mark it as answered

Comment: will do as soon as i have figured out how to :D

Comment: The 'tick' bellow next to the upvote/downvote buttons of the answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

You can't treat an arbitrary array of bytes as a string. You're taking the bytes, converting them to a string, then writing the string into a StreamWriter, which converts the string back to bytes. This will be a lossy operation over a bunch of arbitrary bytes.

Your method `EncryptStringToBytes` is a mistaken concept. You should have a method `EncryptBytes` (and `DecryptBytes`) which don't concern themselves with strings. Then you can pass in a byte array and feed it directly into the `CryptoStream`. How those bytes are interpreted isn't the concern of an encryption algorithm.

So you could tweak your methods as follows:

```
static byte[] EncryptBytes(byte[] bytes, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
    // Check arguments.
    if (bytes == null || bytes.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("bytes");
    if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
    if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
    // Create an Rijndael object
    // with the specified key and IV.
    using (Rijndael rijAlg = Rijndael.Create())
    {
        rijAlg.Key = Key;
        rijAlg.IV = IV;

        // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

        // Create the streams used for encryption.
        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, 
                    CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                csEncrypt.Write(bytes,0,bytes.Length);
                csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
                return msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
static byte[] DecryptBytes(byte[] encryptedBytes, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
    // Check arguments.
    if (encryptedBytes == null || encryptedBytes.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("encryptedBytes");
    if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
    if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

    // Create an Rijndael object
    // with the specified key and IV.
    using (Rijndael rijAlg = Rijndael.Create())
    {
        rijAlg.Key = Key;
        rijAlg.IV = IV;

        // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

        // Create the streams used for decryption.
        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, 
                    CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                csDecrypt.Write(encryptedBytes,0,encryptedBytes.Length);
                csDecrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
                return msDecrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

then test with a roundtrip:

```
using(var rijndael = Rijndael.Create())
{
    var stringToEncrypt = "foobar";
    var bytesToEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt);
    var encryptedBytes = EncryptBytes(bytesToEncrypt, rijndael.Key, rijndael.IV);
    var decryptedBytes = DecryptBytes(encryptedBytes, rijndael.Key, rijndael.IV);
    var originalString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);
    Debug.Assert(string.Equals(stringToEncrypt, originalString, 
                                StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
}
```

hopefully, by this point, it's clear how we've disentangled the string encoding issues from the encryption and how you might now repurpose these methods for any kind of binary data.

Comment: Well i guess i'm too inexperienced for that.... this is just the MSDN code and i tried to make it fit into my application.

Comment: @Mreifenberger There are problems with the code above... working it out now.

Comment: yeah i see my problem now... thanks very much spender! Never expected so much help :)